# Get Maven AbstractMojo @parameters pom tag attributes

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm new on java.

Given that I have a configuration on my pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.custom.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-maven/artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <configuration>
            <providerSelection id="someCustomIdGoesHere">2.0</providerSelection>
        </configuration>
```

How do I call the **URL** attribute ID with in my class?

```
  /**
   * The properties files that will be used when reading properties.
   *
   * @parameter
   * @required
   */
  private String url;
 // hot to get attribute of ID?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible. The configuration-blocks only supports elements and a small number of attributes for behavior.
So the best you can do is change the configuration to

```
<configuration>
  <url>some_value</url>
</configuration>
```

Btw, if you are new to Java, then I'm not sure if writing a custom Maven plugin is the best way to learn. You'll be facing a lot of different aspects of Java and Maven.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there will be a way to add attribute to configuration parameters. I was hoping somethig like from maven-antrun-plugin
`<copy file="${ver.template.dir}/${ver.template.file}" tofile="${ver.template.dir}/${ver.class.name}.java" />`

Comment: Antrun works a bit different. It just picks up the whole configuration-block and feeds it to Ant. And so: yes, you can get the configuration as xml and parse it, however that makes your Mojo very bad to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks! So attribute is not an option for mojo, more likely I need redesign. and I hate parsing xml.